# Print N lines of K long binary strings

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to print a text file n times, but for some reason it's only looping once, here is my code.

```
def makeStrings():
k = int(raw_input("Enter the number of bits in each binary string: "))
n = int(raw_input("Enter the number of binary strings to create: "))
name = raw_input("Enter the name of the file: ")
fileName = name
outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
int(k)
int(n)
for i in range(0,n):
    while(k>0):
        randomNumber= int(random.randint(0,1))
        outputFile.write(str(randomNumber))
        k = k - 1
    outputFile.write("\n")
outputFile.close()
```

If you enter 5 for k and 5 for n, it should write something like this:

```
01110
11011
00011
11011
11100
```

to the file, but it only writes 1 line.
Could anyone give me some insight?

Answer (score 3):

`while(k>0):`

You never reset `k` back to its initial value. This loop only happens once

probably should just use a range again

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(k):
        # Don't subtract k...
```

Or, even condense it all down

```
with open(fileName, "w") as outputFile:
    for i in range(n):
        outputFile.write(''.join(str(random.randint(0,1)) for _ in range(k)))
        outputFile.write("\n")
```

Comment: How would I set k back to it's initial value? Wouldn't that create an infinite loop

Comment: Don't use a while loop